# How to write into a Log file from the batch file?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I have a batch file that triggers  process in Access database. I'd like to write into a log file (just some *.txt file saved in the same folder) time when before the process started and after it was finished.
Is there a command for that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What operating system are you on? The solution is simple, but will depend what system you're on. Also, there are many questions similar to this you should search for first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using > and >> outputs to a file.

eg

```
echo Hello World > hi.txt
```

Will result in a file called `hi.txt` containing the string "Hello World"

```
echo How are you >> hi.txt
```

Will add the line "How are you" to the end of `hi.txt`

This works on both Windows and Unix based OS. (Linux, Mac OS...)

On windows, using `%TIME%` or `%DATE%` in the echo string will output time/date as part of the string.